# How to read the user's preferred date+time format?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I need a representation of the current user's preferred date+time format, like for example: @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

Or in other words: When I print out a NSDate nicely compatible to the preferred locale of the user, then I need that format in string representation as Unicode Standard symbols like in the example above. Is there a way to get this information out from the user's locale?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at NSLocale & NSCalendar & NSDateFormatter...